# How to run particular test cases(it) from a describe.js in Protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I have a scenario below:

1. Log in to the app.
2. Create a Form.
3. Submit the Form.
4. Edit a Form and submit.
5. Log out.

Now I have divided all the above into 5 test cases i.e. it's under one describe. Since I have more than 1000 test cases, I can't go with js file for each of the above test cases. So I created js files for each scenario with multiple test cases (it's).

Now take the above scenario, in which, I need to execute only the test cases 1, 4 and 5. My conf.js is configured like below:

```
specs: ['../scenario1.js','../scenario2.js','../scenario3.js']
```

Kindly help me to execute only the cases which I needed from each scenario.js.

Note: Here comes dependency between scenarios i.e. scenario2's test cases might depend on scenario1's test cases (not all test cases). That why I m looking for a particular execution of test cases.

Comment: which testing framework are you using ?

Comment: for describe use ddescribe() and for it block use iit().

Comment: @AZ_ I can't change every time for each scenario. Thats why I m looking for changes in conf file itself. If I run scenario 2, sometimes, all the test cases needs to be executed. Ayush, I m using jasmine framework.

Comment: you need execute all the test in spec? then you can create the same conf file with only specs you need to run or one conf per spec.

Comment: @AZ_ lets take an example. In my scenario1, I need to run steps 1, 2, 3 and 5. In scenario2, I need to run steps 1, 4 and 5. And in scenario3, I need to run steps 1 and 5. So these different scenarios, I can't change inside the js files every time.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without making changes in spec files, you can keep some conditional env variables in specs and use these to decide when to run what.